# Is there a way to dynamically add columns to table in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a master table containing information relevant to different countries. These Countries have many duplicate columns and many unique coulmns. Is there a way to dynamically add a column name to a Master table.

For example.

Table 1

```
Country Acc 1000 Acc 1010 Acc 1020 etc
UK           x        x         x
UK           x        x         x
```

Table 2

```
Country Acc 1000 Acc 1010 Acc 1030 etc
FR           x        x         x
FR           x        x         x
```

Master

```
Country Acc 1000 Acc 1010  Acc 1020    Acc 1030 etc
FR             x        x         0           x
FR             x        x         0           x   
UK             x        x         X           0
UK             x        x         X           0
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could better normalize this that trying to dynamically add columns to a table.

You could use a view using pivoting to transpose the results when you want to create a user-friendly view.

Option 1, stick with this plan:

- Create a after insert, update, delete trigger and use `execute immediate` to alter the table;

Option 2, normalize:

- Create a `acc` table;
- Edit that one, you would normally do with tables;
- Read up on pivot / unpivot in the [Oracle documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html).